# R: Exponential covariance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, covariance, exponential

I would like to calculate a covariance matrix where the matrix components are obtained by an exponential moving average (i.e. `S(t)=a*Y(t)+(1-a)*S(t-1)`).

It seems to me that `mewma` should do that but when I call the function for a 60,400 matrix I get a 'subsrcript out of bounds error'.

I believe it comes from the line:

```
ucl <- h4[m1[l], m2[a[2] - 1]]
```

Can the `mewma` function be called for a matrix with a dim of more than 9 ?

Otherwise is there an alternative package?

I have followed:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/how-to-compute-an-exponentially-weighted-covariance-matrix-function-in-r

Comment: You should post an example that constructs a 'Y(t)' process.

Comment: I try to reproduce what is presented for instance on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMA_chart